how to add custom scopes to Keycloak
I am using Keycloak version 25 but have difficulties in setting up custom scopes.
What I need is to have JWT token with custom scopes like
{
   "scope": "custom:scope1 custome:scope2"
}

And A client requesting a token will pass the corresponding scopes
When creating a Client Scope, there is no "scope" n Configure a New Mapper. How do I do so?

Actually, I found that I just need to turn on "Include in token scope" and specify the "Consent screen text" in the custom Client scope
